# Is there a known example of a Dirichlet L series having at least one multiple root?

Tags: dirichlet-series

The Davenport-Heilbronn function doesn't have a Dirichlet series since its a linear combination of two L functions. I mention that because its a common myth that this function is an L function.

Comment: $a \, L(s,\chi_5) +\overline{a} \, L(s,\overline{\chi_5})$ is a Dirichlet series, it belongs to the extended Selberg class (it has a functional equation) but it doesn't have an Euler product (its coefficients are not multiplicative) so it is not a L-function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, and it is conjectured that every zero is simple. There are a variety of partial proofs towards this, proving results of the flavor "$X$ percent of zeroes up to height $Y$ are simple."

This is something specific to Dirichlet $L$-functions, as other $L$-functions are known to have higher order zeroes. For instance, Hasse-Weil $L$-functions often have multiple order roots at $s = 1$. (This is a fundamental aspect of the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer Conjecture).

Comment: thank you @mixedmath Do you know of any results that say for instance, every root up to height L is simple? Instead of some percentage of every root up to some height